# Tkinter math operation with DB variable

Tags: python, database, sqlite, tkinter

I need to make a math operation with variables taken from 
a: a database 
b: tkinter entry

```
#Get database number
cantidad = IntVar()
cursor.execute('''SELECT terneros FROM animales''')
cantidad.set(cursor.fetchone())
```

Then, a tkinter entry:

```
ent_peso = Entry (ventana1, textvariable=peso).grid(row=3, column=2)
```

When I try to make the following operation

```
total = StringVar()
total.set(peso*cantidad.get())
messagebox.showinfo("Resultado", "$: "+ total.get())
```

I get this

```
TypeError: getdouble() argument must be str, not tuple
```

Entire code:

```
    peso = IntVar()
    def calcular():
        cantidad = IntVar()
        cursor.execute('''SELECT terneros FROM animales''')
        cantidad.set(cursor.fetchone())
        total = StringVar()
        total.set(peso.get()*cantidad.get())
        messagebox.showinfo("Resultado", "$: "+ total.get())




    ent_peso = Entry (ventana, textvariable=peso).grid(row=3, column=2)
    but_calc = Button(ventana, text="Calcular", command=calcular).place(x=150,y=115)

    ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: convert it to string

Comment: @ADWAN what do hoy mean with “it”?

Comment: _None_ of the code pieces you've provided are enough to reproduce the error you're getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies in the following line of code:

```
cantidad.set(cursor.fetchone())
```

The `cursor.fetchone()` method returns a tuple which contains all the values in your query, in this case, `(terneros,)`.
You should change this line of code to

```
cantidad.set(cursor.fetchone()[0])
```

in order to get the contents of this tuple.